# When i single tap text form field it popup keyboard to input but i wants it done only when user double tap

Tags: forms, flutter, text, focus, textfield

I have text form field with custom draggable widget as parent.I want to input the text only when user double tap the text form and when the single tap done I want nothing to do .As now when i single tap text form field it popup keyboard to input but I want it done only when user double tap.

Comment: Show us some code....

Answer (score 2):

This will give an idea,

First Declare a boolean

```
 var enableField=false;
```

Then, wrap your `TextFormField` inside `InkWell` and on `onDoubleTap` of `InkWell` set `enableField` to `true`. Pass this this `enableField` to `enabled` property of `TextFormField`

```
          InkWell(
            onDoubleTap: (){
              setState(() {
                enableField=true;
              });
            },
            child: TextFormField(
              enabled: enableField,
             ...
```

Comment: Brother it only happens one time and in another time single tap popup the keyboard again..

Comment: Then once you done editing on `TextFormField` use `onFieldSubmitted` to `setSatte` of `enableField=false` again.

Comment: thanks..I will give a try

Comment: check my code please.

Answer (score 1):

`````
var enableField=false;
Container(
          child: InkWell(
        onDoubleTap: () {

          setState(() {
            enableField = true;

          });
        },
        child:  TextFormField(
            enabled: enableField,
            onFieldSubmitted: (a) {
              setState(() {
                enableField = false;
              });
            },

            style: TextStyle(color: white, fontSize: 18),
            // initialValue: 'your initial text',
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
              focusColor: Colors.red,
              border: InputBorder.none,
              hintText: getUserName(),
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: white, fontSize: 18),
            ),````
`````